# Bitbucket - Add default task when creating a pull requst

Tags: process, bitbucket, workflow, pull-request

I am looking into improving the workflow my colleague and myself are using for BitBucket. Something that is often forgotten is the documentation for the feature we are working on therefore I thought I good way to 'don't forget' would be to add a Task as soon as a Pull request is created for a particular branch.

The first think a developer should do after creating the Pull Request would be:
 - Add a comment, something like WIP (Work in Progress)
 - Create a task underneath, something like 'Add documentation'

In this way, we won't be able to 'Merge' the branch into 'Develop' if All tasks are not completed (this is how it is currenly configured).

Rather than having the developer to do so, it would be good if we can have the system to do so as soon as we create the Pull Request.

Is that possible?

I had searchd on Internet, to be honest I didn't understand if taht functionality comes with like the Premium package or if it is an Add-On...who knows.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian recently added a 'Default Pull Request Tasks' feature to Bitbucket Cloud.
The same functionality was previously available as a Bitbucket app, but it was  removed in May 2020. It's now a native feature.

Product announcement: https://bitbucket.org/blog/bitbucket-cloud-product-updates-august-2022

Feature details: https://bitbucket.org/blog/default-pull-request-tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It is free for 30 days.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1225598/default-tasks-for-pull-requests?tab=pricing&hosting=datacenter

I did not find any free solutions.